# Primes from the Pan Digital

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, knowledge, no-computers

Pan Digital Number is the smallest with all the digits 1 to 9 with no repeats.

When looking forwards or backwards, eleven Primes can be extracted from that number preserving the same sequence.

Among the eleven primes, one of each 4 digit, 5 digit, 8 digit ones exist. Rest are single and double digit primes.

Just using deductive reasoning and no brute force, deduce all the primes.

Comment: I may need a computer to determine if an 8-digit number is prime. Is that allowed?

Comment: For just one number..you may need it. All others should follow from logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using:

> $123456789$

we find:

> $2,3,5,7$
>  $23,67,89$ and $43$
>  4-digit - either $4567$ or $4321$ (no even numbers, multiples of $3$ or $5$)
>  5-digit - $34567$, $56789$ or $76543$
>  $23456789$, because the other option is a multiple of $3$, and this one's reverse is a multiple of $2$.
>
>  I can't yet see how to find the $4$ and $5$ digit primes without using a computer/calculator.

Comment: I am also stuck at the same point. There are still 3 numbers to rule out, but I don't see any way to do so by logic. I know which numbers they are and their factors are absolutely not trivial to find.

Comment: Small calculator will narrow down 4 digit....almost 5 digit..like I commented on hexomino’s Q, you need 1 computer calculation

Comment: @Uvc So you don't consider checking with a calculator if a 4 digit number is prime to be 'brute force'? I would very much do so. There is not much 'deductive reasoning' in using a calcuator.

Comment: You can do by hand  calculations when. Doing small number check....considering the last digit options can be narrowed....I just said calculator as most people use phones to check..

Comment: We are using the calculator sparingly to narrow down final options after initial reasoning...you